# Docker & angular: Circular dependency after performing ngcc

Tags: angular, docker, npm

Here my first `Dockerfile`:

```dockerfile
# Stage 1: Build an Angular Docker Image
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2, use the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I runs well, but it's very slow.

In order to speed it up, I've change to:

```dockerfile
# Stage 1: Build an Angular Docker Image
FROM node as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm ci --only=production
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@^9.1.4 && \
    npm install -g @angular/compiler-cli^9.1.4 && \
    npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@^0.901.4 && \
    npm install @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr@^0.901.4
RUN ngcc
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

# Stage 2, use the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

As you can see, I've replaced `RUN npm install` by:

```dockerfile
RUN npm ci --only=production
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@^9.1.4 && \
    npm install -g @angular/compiler-cli^9.1.4 && \
    npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@^0.901.4 && \
    npm install @angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr@^0.901.4
RUN ngcc
```

It also works well, but suddenlt, I'm getting a lot of `Circular source file mapping dependency` warning messages:

> Warning: Unable to fully load /app/node_modules/ra-ng/lib/security/jwt-request-client.d.ts for source-map flattening: **Circular source file mapping dependency**: /app/node_modules/ra-ng/lib/security/jwt-request-client.d.ts.map -> /app/node_modules/ra-ng/lib/security/jwt-request-client.d.ts.map

Any ideas?

**NOTE:**

`npm run build` performs: `ng build --prod`

Comment: Out of curiosity: why building the app in the dockerfile? Couldn't you just deploy directly the pre-built files? In this way the build would be performed once, while preparing the image. (sorry if the terminology is not exact: I know Angular, but just a bit of Docker)

Comment: [Docker multistaging](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)

Comment: @Jordi I have usually seen this happen when I rerun the `ngcc` command, but it looks like you are running it on a clean environment so that can't be the issue. Besides that, I would advise you to upgrade to angular 11 or 10 if you can't go to 11. A lot of improvements have been made to the ngcc compiler in the last couple of months. Since the ngcc compiler is brand new it good to keep up with the latest version of angular.

Comment: First, I perform `ngcc` and then `ng build --prod`.. Perhaps it's performing `ngcc` twice...?

Comment: That could be it does run ngcc before ng build automatically, but it will only compile a module if it can't find it and it is needed for the ng build. Maybe you could try to remove the explicit ngcc compilation